# CSS height at least #px?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to set a CSS element (div in this case) to a certain height, unless the content in it causes it to be larger? I have a CSS layout, and I want my "content" div to be at least 600px high, but is there's 700px of content, allow it to be extended.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
div {
    min-height: 600px;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind this is not backwards compatible - only works from IE9+

Comment: Actually it's supposed to work in IE7+. I don't feel like testing it though.